# Error in creating PDF in Latex in Texstudio

Tags: pdf, latex, presentation

I want to create presentation in latex. Following is the code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Electrical Machines}
\subtitle{Electromechanical Energy Conversion}
\author{Vivek kumar Pal}
\institute{Department of Electrical Engineering\\VJTI}
\date{\today}   

\subject{Electricals}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Code is getting executed properly. But following error is coming for creating pdf :

```
does not look like a valid PDF document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation. Retrying every two seconds.
```

Kindly help in this and let know the reason.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with PowerPoint?  It doesn't seem so.  If not, please remove the "powerpoint" tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing content. Once you add it it will work properly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Electrical Machines}
\subtitle{Electromechanical Energy Conversion}
\author{Vivek kumar Pal}
\institute{Department of Electrical Engineering\\VJTI}
\date{\today}   

\subject{Electricals}

\begin{document}
Enter content here.
\end{document}
```

`